# Why doesn't this isNumeric function work with fgets?

Tags: c, c-strings

I'm writing a small program that accept input from `stdin` and check whether it contains numbers or not. The problem is that it only works with `scanf()` and not with `fgets` (I would like to avoid using `scanf`).

To do it I'm using `isDigit` function from `<ctype.h>` and the following function that check every character of the array:

```c
int isNumeric(const char *buf) {
 for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(buf); i++)
   if(isDigit(buf[i]) == 0)
     return false;
  return true;
}
```

And this is the driver code:

```c
// This does not works
int main(void) {
 char c[256];

 fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);

 if(isNumeric(c))
   puts("Is numeric");
 else
   puts("Not numeric");
}
// ####################
// This works
int main(void) {
 char c[256];

 scanf("%s", c);

 if(isNumeric(c))
   puts("Is numeric");
 else
   puts("Not numeric");
}
```

The expected output should be, obviously, "Is numeric".
What I'm doing wrong with `fgets`?

Comment: Are you aware that _Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character._? Found in [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). So, the newline may disturb your `isNumeric()`.

Comment: Your loop is inefficient, calling strlen will effectively call the function causing stack operations on every iteration, just use buf[i]!='\0' instead, then in your loop use buf[i] >= '0' && buf[i] <= '9' instead of calling isDigit.  Also when calling fgets or any function that returns something, check the return code before use.

Comment: Note that the function in `<ctype.h>` in standard C is `isdigit()` and not `isDigit()`.  I've no idea where you're actually getting `isDigit()` from, but it isn't standard C.  However, if it works for you, that's fine.  There are extensions, and using them is fine too, as long as you know it is an extension (and hence not necessarily available everywhere).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

> Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case **str will contain that newline character**.

So before feeding the string to `isNumeric` you need to trim the trailing eol character.